# Better selection from Pandas DatatimeIndex by weekday and time

Tags: python, pandas

Problem: Selection from Pandas `DatetimeIndex` by weekday and time. For example, I would like to select all items between Tuesday 20:00 and Friday 06:00.

Question: Is there a better solution than my solution below?

I have an existing solution (see below), but I don't like it too much for the following reasons:

- It converts the timestamps to floats and does float comparisons, with the usual accuracy issues.
- It does neither seem very elegant nor pythonic to convert from a rich datatype to a primitive datatype with a contrived mapping for the task at hand.
- Selections across Sunday (weekday 6) - Monday (weekday 0) require klugdy special treatment (not part of example below).

My working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time
import calendar

# The DatetimeIndex to selection from
idx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31', freq='H')

# Converts a datetime to a time-of-day fraction in [0, 1)
def datetime_to_time_frac(t):
    return t.hour / 24 + t.minute / (24 * 60) + t.second / (24 * 60 * 60)

# Converts a datetime to a float representing weekday (Monday: 0 to Sunday: 6) + time-of-day fraction in [0, 1)
def datetime_to_weekday_time_frac(t):
    return t.weekday + datetime_to_time_frac(t)

# DatetimeIndex converted to float
idx_conv = datetime_to_weekday_time_frac(idx)

# Boolean mask selecting items between Tuesday 20:00 and Friday 06:00
mask = (idx_conv >= calendar.TUESDAY + datetime_to_time_frac(time(20, 0)))\
     & (idx_conv <= calendar.FRIDAY + datetime_to_time_frac(time(6, 0)))

# Validation of mask in a pivot table
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx[mask])
df['Date'] = df.index.date
df['Weekday'] = df.index.weekday
weekdays = list(calendar.day_abbr)
df['WeekdayName'] = df.Weekday.map(lambda x: weekdays[x])
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'WeekdayName'], columns='Hour', values='Weekday', aggfunc='count')
```

The final pivoted output shows that the code does the right thing, but I have a feeling that there is a more elegant and idiomatic way to approach this problem.

*(Code is based on Python 3 with recent Pandas.)*

[image: Pivoted final output for code validation]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use the internal index functionality in `pandas` to index this a little more cleanly. I'm avoiding the conversion to fractional time, and admittedly what I'm doing only works for whole hours. The basic difference is using pandas built-in functionality and avoiding `calendars` as an import. Here's what I've done that is mostly equivalent to your very specific example of Tues-Fri, but if you only need intervals on the hour, you could adapt this to the more general case.

```py
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)

# Build a series of filters for each part of your weekly interval.
tues = (df.index.weekday == 1) & (df.index.hour >= 6)
weds_thurs = df.index.weekday.isin([2,3])
fri = (df.index.weekday == 4) & (df.index.hour <= 20)

# The mask is just the union of all those conditions
mask = tues | weds_thurs | fri

# now apply the mask and the rest is basically what you were doing
df = df.loc[mask]
df['Date'] = df.index.date
df['Weekday'] = df.index.weekday
df['WeekdayName'] = df.index.weekday_name
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'WeekdayName'], columns='Hour', values='Weekday', aggfunc='count')
```

Now I see output that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Got the Tues/Fri times reversed, but same difference.

Answer (score 0):

The following should achieve what you're looking for:

```py
def make_date_mask(day_start, time_start, day_end, time_end, series):
    flipped = False
    if day_start > day_end:
        # Need to flip the ordering, then negate at the end
        day_start, time_start, day_end, time_end = (
            day_end, time_end, day_start, time_start
        )
        flipped = True

    time_start = datetime.strptime(time_start, "%H:%M:%S").time()
    time_end = datetime.strptime(time_end, "%H:%M:%S").time()

    # Get everything for the specified days, inclusive
    mask = series.dt.dayofweek.between(day_start, day_end)
    # Filter things that happen before the begining of the start time
    # of the start day
    mask = mask & ~(
        (series.dt.dayofweek == day_start) 
        & (series.dt.time < time_start)
    )
    # Filter things that happen after the ending time of the end day
    mask = mask & ~(
        (series.dt.dayofweek == day_end) 
        & (series.dt.time > time_end)
    )

    if flipped:
        # Negate the mask to get the actual result and add in the
        # times that were exactly on the boundaries, just in case
        mask = ~mask | (
            (series.dt.dayofweek == day_start) 
            & (series.dt.time == time_start)
        ) | (
            (series.dt.dayofweek == day_end) 
            & (series.dt.time == time_end)
        )
    return mask
```

Using it with your example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "dates": pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31', freq='H')
})
filtered_df = df[make_date_mask(6, "23:00:00", 0, "00:30:00", df["dates"])]
```

`filtered` looks like:

```
                  dates
143 2019-01-06 23:00:00
144 2019-01-07 00:00:00
311 2019-01-13 23:00:00
312 2019-01-14 00:00:00
479 2019-01-20 23:00:00
480 2019-01-21 00:00:00
647 2019-01-27 23:00:00
648 2019-01-28 00:00:00
```